# How to append select inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append

I am trying to append select options inside loop but I am unable to understand how to do that. My normal code in jquery is like this:
          var myselect2 = $('');

```
  var myselect2 = $('<select>');
   myselect2.append( $('<option disabled selected value ></option >').val("").html("") );
       myselect2.append( $('<option ></option>').val("a").html("a") );
       myselect2.append( $('<option ></option>').val("b").html("b") );
       myselect2.append( $('<option ></option>').val("c").html("c") );
       myselect2.append( $('<option ></option>').val("d").html("d") );

           $('#health_institutions1').append(myselect2.html());
```

and my html code is :

```
 <select multiple="" class="form-control" id="health_institutions1">
```

I am trying this code below but no luck

```
  myselect2.append( $('<option disabled selected value ></option >').val("").html("") );
  $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: url()+'/patient_occupancies.json',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (datavalues1) {



         $.each(datavalues1, function( i, val ) {
                   var indicator1 = val.indicators;

                   if (indicator1 === 'Outpatient visits') {
                     var x = val.District;
                     myselect2.append( $('<option ></option>').val(x).html(x) );
                      //  console.log(textToInsert);
                  console.log(x);                   }

         });


       }
   });

$('#health_institutions1').append(myselect2.html());
```

It is not working how can I append options in my case.

Comment: "it's not working" - care to elaborate?  Does it give a script error?  Does it not get to your code?  What's the value of `datavalues1` ... is it an array or is there an additional property first?

Comment: it has just values like a b c d

Comment: In an array? As property of a javascript object?  xml?  json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following code should achieve what you want.

```
var myselect2 = $('<select>');
myselect2.append($('<option disabled selected value ></option >').val("").html(""));

var items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    myselect2.append($('<option ></option>').val(items[i]).html(items[i]));
}

$('#health_institutions1').append(myselect2.html());
```

Basically we are creating an array `items` with 4 values. `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Then running a for loop to append each one to `myselect2`.

Remember if you are doing an AJAX call like the updated question you need to append it to your page after running creating the element. That means you need to put your final append within the AJAX callback. For example.

```
success: function(datavalues1) {
    $.each(datavalues1, function(i, val) {
        var indicator1 = val.indicators;

        if (indicator1 === 'Outpatient visits') {
            var x = val.District;
            myselect2.append($('<option ></option>').val(x).html(x));
            //  console.log(textToInsert);
            console.log(x);
            $('#health_institutions1').append(myselect2.html());
        }
    });
}
```

That will ensure that it only gets appended after the AJAX call success.

Comment: it is not working like this :          $.each(datavalues1, function( i, val ) {
                   var indicator1 = val.indicators;

                   if (indicator1 === 'Outpatient visits') {
                     var x = val.District;
                     myselect2.append( $('<option ></option>').val(x).html(x) );
                      //  console.log(textToInsert);
                    //  datavalues.push(x);
                   }

         });

Comment: What ajax? There is no ajax.

Comment: @NilaySingh Also posting code in comments isn't helpful at all. No way can I read that code.

Comment: @NilaySingh Try moving `$('#health_institutions1').append(myselect2.html());` within your AJAX call. That line is getting run before your response is given.

Comment: It worked I put $('#health_institutions1').append(myselect2.html()); inside ajax call thanks can you edit your answer

Comment: @NilaySingh Done. Considering accepting and up-voting if you feel like it helped! Happy coding!!